# shared_ptr using gcc compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw

I am trying to use shared_ptr in c++. I am using MinGw gcc compiler.

My g++ version is 4.8.1.

When I try to use std::shared_ptr, it says it does not name a type.

Is this because it is part of c++ 11, and that is not supported in the compiled I am using?

Or do I need to set a flag to use c++ 11 features?

EDIT: I tried adding the flag to enable c++ to my makefile, and it still gives an error.

My header where shared_ptr is used is as follows

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <memory>

namespace WavFileTools
{
    class WavFile;
}

class WavFileTools::WavFile
{

    public: 

        typedef std::vector<unsigned char> PCMData8_t;
        typedef std::vector<unsigned short int> PCMData16_t;

        struct WavFileHeader {

            int num_channels;
            int sample_rate;
            int bits_per_sample;
        };

        static std::shared_ptr<WavFile> LoadWavFromFile(std::string filename);

    private:
        WavFile(void);  

    private:                
        WavFileHeader m_header;
        PCMData16_t m_data16;
        PCMData8_t m_data8;
};
```

And the makefile...

```
CC := g++
CFLAGS := -g -O2 -std=c++0x
BIN_DIR := bin
BUILD_DIR := build
SRC_DIR := src
MAIN := WavFileTool
TARGET := wavfiletool.exe
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:$(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)

$(BIN_DIR)/$(TARGET): CREATE_DIRS $(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).o $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS)  -o $@ 

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(MAIN).o: $(SRC_DIR)/WavFileTool.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

CREATE_DIRS: 
    if not exist $(BIN_DIR) mkdir $(BIN_DIR)
    if not exist $(BUILD_DIR) mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)

CLEAN:
    if exist $(BIN_DIR) rmdir /Q /S  $(BIN_DIR) # /S allows deleting non-empty folder, and /Q prevents confirmation required
    if exist $(BUILD_DIR) rmdir /Q /S $(BUILD_DIR)
```

and the error

```
In file included from src/WavFile.cpp:1:0:
src/WavFile.h:26:10: error: 'shared_ptr' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
   static std::shared_ptr<WavFile> LoadWavFromFile(std::string filename);
```

Comment: You need the compiler flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In the `Makefile` `$(CC_FLAGS)` isn't set. Did you mean to put `$(CFLAGS)` there?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I thought makefile typos were done nipping me in the butt this project...

Comment: Galik, you should put your answer as an official answer!